# Make not work using My redefine implicit rules

Tags: build, makefile

I want to separate the source code and object code to a different directory.

The following is my directory tree:

```
.
|-- bsp
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- x86
|       |-- begin.s
|       |-- dummy.s
|       |-- helloos.s
|       |-- lowlevel_init.s
|       `-- Makefile
|-- buildrules
|   |-- builder.rules
|   |-- linker.rules
|   `-- subdir.rules
|-- configure
|   `-- helloos.lds
|-- hypervisor
|   |-- font.c
|   |-- int.c
|   |-- int_entry.s
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- mouse.c
|   `-- start.c
|-- include
|   |-- common.h
|   `-- font.h
|-- lib
|   |-- lib.s
|   `-- Makefile
|-- Makefile
`-- README.md
```

I want to Create a "obj" subdir on the root(TOP) dir. put all obj file into it.

Like the following:

.

```
|-- bsp
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- x86
|       |-- begin.s
|       |-- dummy.s
|       |-- helloos.s
|       |-- lowlevel_init.s
|       `-- Makefile
|-- buildrules
|   |-- builder.rules
|   |-- linker.rules
|   `-- subdir.rules
|-- configure
|   `-- helloos.lds
|-- hypervisor
|   |-- font.c
|   |-- int.c
|   |-- int_entry.s
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- mouse.c
|   `-- start.c
|-- include
|   |-- common.h
|   `-- font.h
|-- lib
|   |-- lib.s
|   `-- Makefile
|-- Makefile
|-- obj
|   |-- begin.o
|   |-- dummy.o
|   |-- font.o
|   |-- helloos.o
|   |-- int_entry.o
|   |-- int.o
|   |-- lib.o
|   |-- lowlevel_init.o
|   |-- mouse.o
|   `-- start.o
`-- README.md
```

And then, This is my implementation:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $<

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $<
```

but I don't like this implementation.

I want to write it like this :

```
    $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<


    $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.s
        $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

if i do that, Make not follow these rules, but it uses implicit rules.

Thanks you for you help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Welcome any puzzled.

Comment: When you link all those object files together into an executable or shared library, what are the make dependencies for the final rule?  Do they reference $(OBJDIR)/*.o files, or just *.o files?  If the latter, make will decide, from that, that it needs to build files named begin.o, not TOP/obj/begin.o, look for a rule for building such a file, and not find one.

Comment: Is the target `all` or the target you're trying to invoke somehow depends on `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` ? Show us a reduced version of a working (with the errors you see) Makefile that we can try it out ?

Comment: I got it. because I don't write preresquisites like $(OBJDIR)/%.o .

Comment: OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
$(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
all: $(OBJS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implicit rule will work if you use `VPATH`

```
VPATH = bsp hypervisor lib

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html :

> The value of the make variable VPATH specifies a list of directories that make should search.
>
> For example,

```
 VPATH = src:../headers
```

> specifies a path containing two directories, src and ../headers, which make searches in that order.
>
> With this value of VPATH, the following rule,

```
foo.o : foo.c
```

> is interpreted as if it were written like this:

```
foo.o : src/foo.c
```

Comment: You mean the "VPATH" in Makefile like "PATH" in shell.?